# How to move form box to a new location

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a windows form  project, and I want the whole form to change location automatically, but the truth is that I  have no idea what to call, and where to call it. I have searched online, and all code I discovered was incomplete.  I am fairly new at this, so it did not help me. 
Here is the code that I am working with, if it helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SoundPlayer _soundplayer;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.sound);
            player.Play();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = new Form2();
            myForm.Show();
        }


        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            _soundplayer.PlayLooping();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just set [`Form.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the required coords.

Comment: Would have been quite easy to use Visual Studio to see which methods/properties are exposed.

Comment: When do you wont the form to move? Which form should move, form1 or form2?

Answer (score 4):

Change the Location for the form:

```
this.Location = new Point(400, 500);
```

You just need to decide which event will trigger this code; for example, the `Click` event of a button.

[MSDN: Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To position forms using the Properties window
In the Properties window, choose the form from the drop-down. Set the form's StartPosition property to Manual.
Type the values for the Location property, separated by a comma, to position the form, where the first number (X) is the distance from the left border of the display area and second number (Y) is the distance from the upper border of the display area.
Note   Expand the Location property to enter the X and Y subproperty values individually.
[Reference MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)